# What is the internal linkage flux of a wire with radius a(shaped like a cylinder)

Tags: electromagnetic, flux, magnetic-flux

How can we clarify that the relation between linkage flux an flux in a cylinder shaped wire is \$ d\lambda=\frac{x^2}{a^2}\ d\phi \$?can we illustrate this by electromagnetic formula?I think I would be able to explain this if I knew the exact definition of linkage flux,I think linkage flux is not a real flux that exists(like flux itself),any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The **flux linkage** is the product of the flux \$ \Phi \$ and the number of coils, N, exist in the wire. Now are you able to explain that?

Comment: I know this ,but here we don't have a coil!it is a cylinder!

Comment: Here you should think of N as the fractional volumes.

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176783/flux-linkage-inside-of-a-conductor